# Explain whats going on with this embedded mp3 player

Tags: html, mp3, flash, embedding

I'm making a first attempt at embedding an mp3 file on a webpage. I've found some code snippets that work, but I don't understand them, and I hate not understanding what I'm writing.  I also can't believe how complicated (and redundant) the code is for a simple player, so I'm thinking this snippet is not as simple as it could be.  On the other hand, most of the code snippets I found look pretty much the same. Could someone explain to me the purpose of each piece of this code, and if it is all necessary?

```
<script src="/assets/audio-player.js"></script>

<object id="audioplayer1" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="290" height="24" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
<param name="data" value="/assets/player.swf" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="playerID=audioplayer1&amp;soundFile=http://example.com/uploads/Fiddle-Tunes.mp3" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="src" value="/assets/player.swf" />
<param name="flashvars" value="playerID=audioplayer1&amp;soundFile=http://example.com/uploads/Fiddle-Tunes.mp3" />

<embed id="audioplayer1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="290" height="24" src="/assets/player.swf" wmode="transparent" menu="false" quality="high" flashvars="playerID=audioplayer1&amp;soundFile=http://www.example.com/uploads/Fiddle-Tunes.mp3" data="/assets/player.swf">
</embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than re-writing the wheel, I'm going to link to a few resources that will help you understand what you're looking at.

1. adobe's [documentation on Object and Embed tags](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html).
2. [Flash Satay method](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay)
3. [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

I usually prefer to use the flash satay method.

Comment: I was just in the middle of rewriting the wheel, when it just made more sense to upvote this answer.

Comment: See, I trust S.O. so much that I don't even search Google anymore. :)  I guess I'll have to learn to do both. Thanks for your time @zzzz.